Pseudocompactness, countable compactness and locally finite open covers
Let $(P_1)$ be the property: Every locally finite open cover of $X$ has finite subcover.
Let $(P_2)$ be the property: Every locally finite open cover of $X$ is finite.
Let $(P_3)$ be the property: Every locally finite family of $X$ is finite.
Lemma. $P_3 \iff$ countably compact.
Proof: ($\impliedby$) Suppose $(A_n)$ is a locally finite family that consists of non-empty distinct sets. Then $F_n = \bigcup_{k\geq n} \overline{A_k} = \overline{\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k}$ is a decreasing family of non-empty closed sets and if it were $x\in \bigcap_n F_n$ then any neighbourhood of $x$ would intersect infinitely many $A_n$, so $\bigcap_n F_n = \emptyset$. This contradicts countable compactness.
($\implies$) If $A\subseteq X$ is countably infinite, then $\{\{x\} : x\in A\}$ is not locally finite, so there exists $x\in X$ such that every neighbourhood of $X$ intersects infinitely many of elements of $A$ ($x$ is an $\omega$-accumulation point of $A$). If $(F_n)$ is any family of closed sets of $X$ with finite intersection property, we can assume its decreasing and take $x_n\in F_n$ and $A = \{x_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now let $x$ be an $\omega$-accumulation point of $A$, then every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects infinitely many $F_n$, hence all of them. So $x\in\bigcap_n F_n$. $\square$
Theorem 1. Countably compact $\iff P_3\implies P_2 \implies P_1 \implies$ pseudocompact.
Proof: (countably compact $\iff P_3$) From above lemma.
($P_3\implies P_2\implies P_1$) Obvious.
($P_1\implies$ pseudocompact) If $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then sets of the form $\{x\in X : n-1 < f(x) < n+1\}$ form a locally finite open cover of $X$, from which we can take a finite subcover, so that $f$ is bounded. So $X$ must be pseudocompact. $\square$
Theorem 2. Pseudocompact + completely regular $\implies P_2$.
Proof: Take a locally finite open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$. If $\mathcal{U}$ isn't finite, take infinite sequence $(V_n)$ of distinct, non-empty elements of $\mathcal{U}$. Pick $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $x_n\in V_n$ such that $f_n(x_n) = n$ and $f_n\equiv 0$ outside of $V_n$. Then $f = \sum_n f_n$ is well-defined and continuous because $\mathcal{U}$ is locally finite, and its unbounded, which contradicts that $X$ is pseudocompact. So we see that any locally finite open cover of $X$ needs to be finite. $\square$
Proposition. Compact $\iff$ paracompact + $P_1$.
Proof: Obvious. $\square$
Question: Does the properties $P_1$ and $P_2$ have a name in the literature?
The reason I am asking for this is because I think that pi-base, the online database of topological spaces, would benefit from having such properties. However, one needs to name it somehow. Any ideas?
Edit: It seems that property $P_1$ doesn't have a name in the literature, but it's known, see e.g. Hereditarily compact spaces by Stone, or Encyclopedia of general topology for this and various other properties between countable compactness and pseudocompactness.

Engelking 3.10.3(ii): Countably compact spaces have the property that every locally finite family of nonempty sets (need not be open) is finite. It's probably an iff (the Hausdorff condition is superfluous probably).  That's stronger than (P2).  Not sure if it's equivalent.

@PatrickR Since $(P_2)$ is equivalent to pseudocompactness for Tychonoff spaces, and there exist pseudocompact Tychonoff spaces which aren't countably compact, its clearly not equivalent. But it would provide another property $(P_3)$ which would be placed between countably compact and $(P_2)$

Sorry, $(P_3)$ is, as you say, most likely equivalent to countable compactness. I meant to say (couldn't edit in time) that we can probably replace compact by countably compact in the string of implications in my theorem 1.

@PatrickR I've updated my question with a lemma which says countable compactness is equivalent to $(P_3)$. As far as I can see, I've never used any Hausdorff, or other separation axioms assumption.

$P_2$ has been called feeble compactness since 1955: wikipedia

Minor thing. (P2) and (P3) should be phrased in terms of a cover of $X$ by nonempty open sets, or a family of nonempty sets.

@PatrickR Why? If I add or remove the empty set, the property will still hold. Unless you consider indexed families where elements can repeat, but I'm not considering them.

Right.  But strictly speaking, nothing in a "family of sets" prevents repetitions. (a "family" is usually indexed by some index set.  "Collection of sets" would be more in line with what you are thinking, i.e., a set of subsets of $X$).  I guess for "cover of $X$" it's always a collection of sets vs a family? I think we all understand what should be meant here.

I don't think there really is a consensus on this, and since its not a very important detail in this case, I'll keep it as it is.
